# modify/update or cancel subscription of user in paypal using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have 3 types of plans for users:

- 1 user plan.
- 3 users plan.
- 6 users plan.

The subscription code for these is working fine.

But now what I want is this: If user A selects the "3 users" plan for monthly subscription and after that same user A selects the "6 users" plan, then I want to cancel or update the "3 users plan" so "user A" will have subscription to the "6 users plan".

Is this possible or not?

I have found code to cancel a subscription:

```
<A HREF="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_subscr-find&alias=alice%40mystore%2ecom"><IMG BORDER="0"SRC="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_unsubscribe_LG.gif"></A>
```

Can i use this code ?

Please suggest me as I have not much experience with paypal.

Thanks.